# UWsim gui doesnt start

Tags: ros, uwsim

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I recently installed did a packaged based installation for the UWsim.
But when I do rosrun Uwsim UWsim......it executes correcltly till the point where it starts printing
**[ INFO] [1465903418.261073092]: ForceSensor_ROSPublisher Waiting for physics to be initialized...**
for all iternity and continues to do that.....what should i do???

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/236907/uwsim-gui-doesnt-start/) by [bhujbalshreyas](https://answers.ros.org/users/27170/bhujbalshreyas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-06-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

That message means the physics simulation is required and it is waiting for it to initialize. It can take some time depending on your computer (no more than twice the vehicle models loading time), the message will be displayed each second in any case. You can check if other scenes are running as the default one is the only one that uses that kind of sensors. Try running rosrun uwsim uwsim --configfile shipwreck.xml and see if that scene is correctly running.

---

Originally posted by [Javier Perez](https://answers.ros.org/users/3430/javier-perez/) with karma: 486 on 2016-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0